# da error la libreria jquery cuando traigo un json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plotly

Hola estoy tratado de crear una gráfica con la librería plotly js pero me da un error con la librería jquery y no me muestra las gráficas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No le presten atención que dice grafico.js eso es el jquery.

Ese es el archivo donde tendría que traer la grafica, se llama es una funcion la cual tiene toda las instrucciones:

```
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel panel-heading">
                    Graficas con plotly js (facultad autodidacta)
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div id="cargaLineal"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div id="cargaBarras"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cargaLineal').load('<?php echo constant('URL');?>main/GraficaBarra');
        $('#cargaBarras').load('<?php echo constant('URL');?>main/GraficaBarra');
    });
</script>
```

Este es otro archivo que contiene la configuración de la grafica :

```
function GraficaBarra(){

    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','bavproyecto');

        $sql="SELECT fecha,id 
                from reporte order by fecha";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        $valoresY=array();//montos
        $valoresX=array();//fechas
        var_dump(mysqli_fetch_row($result));
        while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $valoresY[]=$ver[1];
            $valoresX[]=$ver[0];
        }

        $datosX=json_encode($valoresX);
        $datosY=json_encode($valoresY);
     
     echo "
    <div id='graficaBarras'></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function crearCadenaBarras(json){
            var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
            var arr = [];
            for(var x in parsed){
                arr.push(parsed[x]);
            }
            return arr;
        }
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

        datosX=crearCadenaBarras(".$datosX.");
        datosY=crearCadenaBarras(".$datosY.");

        var data = [
            {
                x: datosX,
                y: datosY,
                type: 'bar'
            }
        ];

        Plotly.newPlot('graficaBarras', data);
    </script>
    ";
    }
```

Si trae las funcion porque hice una prueba mandando imprimir algo y si se imprime con todos los datos, por lo momento el unico error es el de jquery que es el json

Comment: El problema se debe a que no estás devolviendo un `JSON`, sino un `HTML`. Todo lo que pretendes hacer en dicho `HTML` deberías hacerlo en el `success` del `load`

Comment: y el resultado de la consulta http???

Comment: @Marcos hola me podrias dar un ejemplo porfa